# Error Build Eclipse Windows for cross compile arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, yocto, eclipse-cdt

I have a sdk package mounted on an embedded linux for the IMX6 device that the old developer gave me.
I made some settings that was in the Readme but as much as I try I get the same error and did not find a similar error on the internet. My environment is with eclipse/Windows 11/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
I get the following error message:

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Thank you

[image]
I wanted to at least build the project. But I don't go through that phase.

[image]
as much as he says he did not find the cc1plus file he exists in the directory maybe lacks some variable environment, but I am not an expert in this type of environment.

Sim essas partes configurei conforme o readme
[image]

Comment: The images don't show what we need to see in order to help you. Low-hanging fruit: In project properties->C/C++ Build->Settings go to Cross Settings and make sure you pointed Eclipse at the correct folder.

Comment: Sim essas partes configurei conforme o readme

Comment: I recommend sticking to English. It works better around here. Matching the readme is not nearly as important as matching reality. The path provided to Eclipse in the third image does not seem to align with the location you point out with Explorer in image 2.

Comment: Sorry, but they are within the same directory yes is that the path ended up getting too long

Comment: remembering that I did not change the tree of directories I received so from the old developer

Comment: I'll take your word on that. So one bit of low-hanging fruit worth investigating: Odd things happen when a path crosses 260 characters. Not all tools are bright enough to handle the long paths.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that way and return here.

Comment: Problem solved, actually the path to the directory was too long after renaming the path now I can build.